# WebApi controller summary is not showing on Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

When I enable this documentation feature through Swagger I'm able to see all kind of information about my documentation but there is no details about my Controller name detail/description.

How to show controller documentation content like below example?

```
/// <summary> 

/// Represents the alert api controller class.

/// <summary>

public class XYZController : ApiController
{

}
```

On enabling swagger I'm not able to see this content any where `Represents the XYZ api controller class. here`

However I able to see my all method description.

Answer (score 42):

1.) Right click the project and Edit projname.csproj
Add the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2.) Add the following to AddSwaggerGen in ConfigureServices

```
  // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

For more details goto:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: This is the one that helped me the most.

Comment: brillaint thank you

Comment: awesome solution....

Answer (score 21):

you need to add IncludeXmlComments extension in AddSwaggerGen as below:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new Info
            {
                Title = "My APIs",
                Version = "v1.0",
                Description = "REST APIs "
            });

            **// Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.**
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);            
        });
```

[For more details refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 14):

This is possible, See @Liversage answer on this page https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/572

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlPath = ...;
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
});
```

Comment: ", includeControllerXmlComments: true" this part helped me a lot. This was missing for me in order to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Is there following code in the SwaggerConfig class?

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {

                    c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\YourAssemlyName.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
```

Answer (score 5):

As some guys above have reply already, I guess the question was about this:

```
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
s.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
```

set `includeControllerXmlComments: true` will allow to take summary of controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the following issue :
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/572

It is currently not possible to display the controller summary, according to the maintainer:

`The reason this has been low on the priority list is because it's not something I've run into issues with. You can absolutely describe what every action in your API does using XML comments on your actions.`

Answer (score 2):

in my case, I only needed to mark to use the XML document
[image]

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<DocumentationFile>C:...\CertReports.Host.xml</DocumentationFile>
```

Comment: There's a screenshot, but no direction of how to get to the screen...

Answer (score 1):

now, in .net core is easy

```
config.UseControllerSummaryAsTagDescription = true;
```

Comment: btw,this is use NSwag's solution